# Find the number of columns between the first and last non NA value

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe,

```
a1=c(9,8,rep(NA,5))
a2=c(3,NA,3,NA,3,NA,4)
a3=c(11,6,7,NA,5,NA,NA)
k<-as.data.frame(rbind(a1,a2,a3))
```

I would like to add a column that indicates the number of columns from the first until the last non NA value. That is for the first row the value in this additional column would be 2, for the second row it would be 7, and for the last it would be 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could loop over the rows (`apply` and `MARGIN = 1`), get the index of non-NA elements (`which` + `!is.na`), extract the `min/max` (`range`), take the `diff`erence` and add 1

```
k$new <- apply(k, 1, function(x) {
       i1 <- which(!is.na(x))
         i2 <- diff(range(i1))
        i2 + 1 })
```

---

Or using `max.col` as a vectorized approach.  Convert the data into logical matrix, apply `max.col` with `ties.method` as `first` and `last` to get the position of first or last max value (`TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0) in each row.  As it is a logical matrix, this is basically looking for the first and last TRUE positions in each row, subtract and add 1

```
max.col(!is.na(k), "last") - max.col(!is.na(k), "first") + 1
[1] 2 7 5
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also be done in `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

k %>%
  mutate(new = pmap(k, ~ {x <- which(!is.na(c(...)))
  y <- max(x) - min(x) + 1
  y}))

   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 new
a1  9  8 NA NA NA NA NA   2
a2  3 NA  3 NA  3 NA  4   7
a3 11  6  7 NA  5 NA NA   5
```

And also this one:

```
k %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = {x <- which(!is.na(c_across(everything())))
    range(x)[2] - range(x)[1] + 1})

# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Rowwise: 
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7   new
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     9     8    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     2
2     3    NA     3    NA     3    NA     4     7
3    11     6     7    NA     5    NA    NA     5
```